# Get-AzureRmSnapshot throws error Get-AzureRmSnapshot : Method 'get_SerializationSettings'

Tags: azure, snapshot

When trying to restore my azure VM from previous snapshot using powershell I get error:

> Get-AzureRmSnapshot : Method 'get_SerializationSettings' in type
>   'Microsoft.Azure.Management.Internal.Resources.ResourceManagementClient'
>   from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
>   does not have an implementation.

Comment: try updating your azure powershell to latest version

Comment: for me `get-azsnapshot` works fine

Comment: powershell is already latest

Comment: not powershell, azure powershell. if its latest why are you using get-azurermsnapshot, not get-azsnapshot?

Answer (score 5):

This is a known issue, documented by Microsoft.
The error indicates that the Azure Resource Manager modules and Az modules are loaded in the same session and those modules are not compatible with each other.

Remediation: Uninstall the conflicting modules. Either Azure Resource Manager modules or the Az modules

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-stack/operator/azure-stack-powershell-install?view=azs-2008

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: It is possible that things won't work for you after performing uninstall or uninstallation gives errors. In such a case, you can clean-up PowerShell (PS) modules manually using following steps. `1.` Close all PowerShell and PowerShell ISE windows `2.` Remove any remaining PowerShell instances by killing its process using task manager `3.` Clear `C:\users\<CurrentUser>\Documents\WindowsPowerShell` directory. Now install only required modules and try running the script again. Name of the folder which contains all PS modules might be `WindowsPowerShell` or `PowerShell` depending upon your OS.

Answer (score 3):

Close powershell and try relauch. It fixed the issue.

Hope it help others who is facing the similar issue.